# Binding to show double as int

Tags: wpf, binding

I want to to show the duration in minutes on my control but I don't want it to show up as with decimal numbers (eg, 65 instead of 65.94503).

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Duration.TotalMinutes, StringFormat=\{0\} minutes}" />
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want an integer to display, I think that all you need to do is set the StringFormat property as follows:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Duration.TotalMinutes, StringFormat=N0}"/>
```

Comment: +1, Additionally `{Binding Duration.TotalMinutes, StringFormat='{0:N0} minutes'}` works.

Answer (score 0):

Do that in code instead of the markup.  You can unit test that easily.  Make TotalMinutes a string or int instead and format it in the ViewModel.